# Add where condition to a Rails controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i have a controller in rails where i call all my players in database.

```
 @candidates = Player.order("created_at DESC")
```

What i need is to show just the ones that have "active=1" un the database.. how can i add the where clause on this..

Tried this.. THE PROBLEM is that active is a table call "users" and im fetching "players" table..

```
@candidates = Player.where("active = ?", "1").order("created_at DESC")
```

Im lost :(

This is part of the player model

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
```

Candidate model

```
class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible  :country_id

end
```

Candidates controller

```
class CandidatesController < SecureController

  skip_authorize_resource :only => [:index, :show]

  # GET /players
  # GET /players.json
  def index
    @candidates = Player.order("created_at DESC")

    position = params[:position]
    minyear = params[:minyear]
    maxyear = params[:maxyear]
    citizen = params[:nation]

  @candidates = Player.scoped # for Rails 3
 if params[:position].present?
   @candidates = @candidates.where(position: position)
 end


 if params[:minyear].present? 
   @candidates = @candidates.where("birthday >= ?", minyear)
 end

 if params[:maxyear].present?
   @candidates = @candidates.where("birthday <= ?", maxyear)
 end

 if params[:minyear].present? && params[:maxyear].present?
   @candidates = @candidates.where("birthday >= ? AND birthday <= ?", minyear, maxyear)
 end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @candidates }
    end

    authorize! :show, :candidates
  end
```

Comment: You need to have a relation between the two tables. Do you have `has` and `belongs_` in the models? Does the Player table relate to the User table with a foreign key in the Player table? (i.e. column user_id in Player)

Comment: What is the relationship between `player` and `user`?

Comment: try this `@candidates = Player.where("players.active = ?", 1).order("created_at DESC")` or `@candidates = Player.where("player.active = ?", 1).order("created_at DESC")` i don't remember

Comment: Monk i just tried that, but its not filtering just active, show all, and must be users.active  becasue, active is the the users table. not players table... ALSo for everyone else i did the relationship user belongs to player.

Comment: And does `User`  `has_many :players`? If you don't show your code, people end up assuming things in their answers. Better to show too much code than not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the users table:

```
Player.joins(:user).where("users.active = ?", "1").order("players.created_at DESC")
```

Also a better way to write the condition is:

```
Player.joins(:user).where(users: { active: true }).order("players.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: I cant... i did this .. and its not filtering, its showing all even the ones with active=0

Comment: i`m not sure but i think you need replace order for right result

Comment: ¿replace order? i dont get it

Comment: I assure you that this works, make sure you are editing the right code, restart your server etc. Monk is right about the order statement, you could run into ambiguous column name error, I updated my answer.

Comment: Actually there is a confusion, in the players table there is other active column... but this is not the column i need to check.. i need to check users.active however when i add your code... then i change the active IN PLAYERS TABLE, works, so i dont know why but its checking the players.active even when we set users.active  anything else im missing ....

Comment: Clarify the question so it's clear what you want to achieve, I'll update my answer.

Comment: i will use the player.active column instead. thanks. my question is other now so i will create a new one